# How to make an "Object " in JSON which will take two "List <Long> " in it?

Tags: java, json, object, testing, postman

I have developed a code in which i have to test it by sending an object to a class named say "hello " which has 2 List in it as :-
Testing is done through "Postman" with  Json as the input format.

```
class Hello 
{
     List<Long> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Long> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
......
}
```

In this the object which i have created is of the form
 `{
    "l1": [104,105],

    "l2" : [-1,-21]
 }`

---

but it gives me the response that :

---

"Message": "Invalid data supplied for request, incorrect data type used.", Leading to a failure , 
Please tell me how to declare the object .
Thanx in advance

Comment: how do you create your json? are you using any libs?

Comment: looks like more of a read/transmit issue than encoding it to json.

Comment: @nafas I have to create the object through "Postman " application , which allows me to make the object, infact i myself want to know the structure format specificiation of this object

Answer (score 0):

```
Long<List> l1=new ArrayList<Long>;
Long<List> l2=new ArrayList<Long>;
```

wouldn't be:

```
List<Long> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Long> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

?

Comment: @everyone , i got my answer , actual  i was doing it in the right way , but the JAR which was system was taking was not updated, so updating them ,helped me